# Placing a Connect to VPN link on desktop - windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I know it's a silly question, but I've created a VPN on my windows 7
and I can't find the way to put the link of the VPN on the desktop
(need to go to cotrol-panel ---> network ---> network and sharing center ---> connect to a netowrk --> my link.

It was very easy on xp/vista....

any ideas ?

(on the same note, can I put it in the programs that I see when I press the windows sign ?)

Thanks.
Dani

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **Network and Sharing Center** click **Change adapter settings** on the left hand side. From there, you can create a shortcut to your VPN connection.

If you want this shortcut in your start menu (the programs that you see when you press the windows sign), simply drag it over the orb, wait till the menu expands, and place it wherever you want.

Comment: There is no option like that on windows 7. only properties and Connect

Comment: Interesting, answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to go through control panel to connect in Windows 7.

In the system tray, there should be an icon for your normal network (wired or wireless). Click it and a list should appear with "Currently connected to" at the top. Underneath that should be a section titled "Dial-up and VPN". Click the connection in there then click connect.

Answer (score 1):

John T's post is helpful, but, for **Windows 10**, or at least on **(1803)**, it seems slightly different (i.e. right side vs. left side, etc.).

There are any number of ways to get to the appropriate settings including:

- Go into settings and search for ***VPN***.  Click ***Change virtual private networks (VPN)***, then in the right side, click ***Change adapter options***.  This opens a ***Network Connections*** window.
- Use the system tray ***Network access*** icon and click the ***Network & Internet Settings*** link.  This pops up a setup window called ***Status / Network Status***.  click ***Change adapter options** that also opens the ***Network Connections*** window.

Once the ***Network Connections*** window is open, the VPN connection(s) of interest should be shown alongside any other connections configured on the computer.  Right-clicking the connection and selecting ***Create Shortcut*** is possible, but as **John T** indicated, drag/drop also works.